# Define Vue methods functions in different js page

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Newbie, sorry in advance for the stupid question

I have a vue component `vuu`

*/path_to_main/vue_file/app.js*

```
const vuu = new Vue({
    el: '#vuu',
    data: {
        latitude: 'longi',
        longitude: 'lati'
    },
    created: function(){this.checkIfGeolocationAvailable();},
    methods: {
        checkIfGeolocationAvailable: function(){
            getLocation(); // <-- this function
        }


    }
});
```

Now I want to define `getLocation()` on a different js page say

*/path_to_main/vue_file/helper.js*

```
function getLocation() {alert("Hello");}
```

How can I do this? or is this a totally wrong approach?

Answer (score 2):

Being modular is never the wrong approach.

Use `es6 modules` and a `transpiler` such as `webpack`, `typescript`, etc.

helper.js

```
export function getLocation() {alert("Hello");}
```

main.js

```
import {getLocation} from './helper.js'
```

Once you start using a transpiler, you should also consider using Vue `single file components`. Furthermore, by leveraging `vue-cli-3`, you can eliminate much of the heavy boilerplate for the transpiler configuration, testing, and building.

Comment: `import {getLocation} from './helper.js'` gives me error `Unexpected token {`

Comment: @SumeetMasih You will get that error if you do not transpile.  Use webpack or similar to transpile your code first.  By default, browsers (and node) do not `understand` module syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I created a helper folder, but it was not necessary

helper/getLocation.js

```
export default function getLocation() {
  alert("Hello")
}
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import getLocation from './helper/getLocation.js'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  mounted() {
    getLocation()
  }
}
</script>
```